# Javascript - Import CSV formatted data to json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a question. For a school project we are making a trading site, so we need a chart. The data that we load in the chart will be csv formatted, so we need to parse that to json format. Here is the code we have so far:
    PHP:

```
    $arrContextOptions=array(
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );

    $data = file_get_contents("https://www.oursite.com/csv_get_data.php?method=graph&ratio=BTC&period=15m", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    $rows = explode("/r/l",$data);
    $s = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $s[] = str_getcsv($row);
    }

    $dataPoints = array();
    foreach($s as $row) {
        $DateTime = $row[0];
        $Open = $row[1];
        $High = $row[2];
        $Low = $row[3];
        $Close = $row[4];
    }
```

Now we need the data to be formatted, so it could fit in this code:
    Javascript:

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
        var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
            type: 'candlestick',
            renderAt: 'chart-container',
            width: '700',
            height: '400',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
                "chart": {
                    "theme": "fusion",
                    "caption": "",
                    "subCaption": "",
                    "numberprefix": "$",
                    "vNumberPrefix": " ",
                    "pyaxisname": "Price",
                    "vyaxisname": "Volume",
                    "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                    "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                    "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                    "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                    "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                    "toolTipPadding": "5"
                },
                "categories": [{
                    "category": [{
                        "label": "5 days ago",
                        "x": "1"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Now",
                        "x": "507"
                    }]
                }],
                "dataset": [{
                    "data": [{
                        "open": "18.74",
                        "high": "19.16",
                        "low": "18.67 ",
                        "close": "18.99",
                        "x": "1",
                    }, {
                        "open": "18.74",
                        "high": "19.06",
                        "low": "18.54",
                        "close": "18.82",
                        "x": "2",
                    }, {
                        "open": "19.21",
                        "high": "19.3",
                        "low": "18.59 ",
                        "close": "18.65",
                        "x": "3",
                    }]
                }]
            }
        });
        fusioncharts.render();
    });
```

The data continues with a lot of datapoints, but they weren't necessary for the example. But can someone help me create the correct json formatted dataset?

EDIT:

In the foreach I entered this line:

```
$dataset[] = array('Open' => $Open, 'High' => $High, 'Low' => $Low, 'Close' => $Close, 'x' => $DateTime);
```

And then in the javascript I tried this:

```
"dataset": [
        <?php
            echo json_encode(array('data' => $dataset));
        ?>
        ]
```

But this doesn't show any graph, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try anything already? Then show us. Which part of the shown JS code do you want to fill dynamically with this - the `data` part under `dataset`? Well then gather that data in the corresponding structure in an array, that you can then json_encode and insert in that position …

Comment: I added an update

Comment: _“But this doesn't show any graph”_ - then check the _output_ this generates, and compare it to your static working version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like you've tried all that much but try using the following to get where you want to be.

First of all you're not really putting anything into the array `$dataPoints`, instead of

```
$dataPoints = array();
foreach($s as $row) {
    $DateTime = $row[0];
    $Open = $row[1];
    $High = $row[2];
    $Low = $row[3];
    $Close = $row[4];
}
```

You should try something like

```
$dataPoints = array();
foreach($s as $row) {
    $dataPoints[] = array(
        'DateTime' => $row[0],
        'Open' => $row[1],
        'High' => $row[2],
        'Low' => $row[3],
        'Close' => $row[4]
    );
}
```

Then it's pretty simple to echo the array as JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/json-encode)

```
echo json_encode($dataPoints);
```

Comment: but how can I implement that json into the javascript

Comment: @Vreesie Make an AJAX call to the PHP file, make the PHP file return the JSON object and use the response of the call in your javascript.

Comment: Okay, I will try! Thank you